# Add Colorbox to a Nextgen Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, galleryview, nextgen-gallery

I have a webshop with t-shirt products. For each t-shirt I have made a NextGen Gallery with the GalleryView (jQuery) template.

The problem is: I want to add a **Colorbox** to the **big picture** from the gallery, but I can't get it work...

This is the preview url:
http://www.jaewhooclothing.com/collection/jae-whoo-limited-t-shirt-design/

I try to use this little script, but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gv_panel img').colorbox({rel:'gal'});
});
</script>
```

Is there someone who know what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`. You forgot to include JQuery?

Comment: Please place `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` somewhere in your head tag.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have added the jQuery include in my head tag. The console tells me: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox'". The Colorbox files are allready included, so what is the problem here?